# BOW / visual codebook / Bag of features using RGB image in openCV?

Tags: opencv, svm

I am able to create a BOW / visual codebook using grayscale images. I using this BOW later for SVM classification. But i want to keep the Color Information also. So, i want to create 3D BOW i.e. with all the channels. But how can i do so?

```
//Obtain the set of bags of features.

char * filename = new char[100];        
Mat input;    

vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
Mat descriptor;

Mat featuresUnclustered;
//The SIFT feature extractor and descriptor
SiftDescriptorExtractor detector;    

//feature descriptors and build the vocabulary
for(int f=0;f<999;f+=50){        
    sprintf(filename,"G:\\testimages\\image\\%i.jpg",f);

    input = imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE); //Load as grayscale                
    //detect feature points
    detector.detect(input, keypoints);
    //compute the descriptors for each keypoint
    detector.compute(input, keypoints,descriptor);        
    //put the all feature descriptors in a single Mat object 
    featuresUnclustered.push_back(descriptor);        
    //print the percentage
    printf("%i percent done\n",f/10);
}        

//Construct BOWKMeansTrainer
//the number of bags
int dictionarySize=200;
//define Term Criteria
TermCriteria tc(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,100,0.001);
//retries number
int retries=1;
//necessary flags
int flags=KMEANS_PP_CENTERS;
//Create the BoW (or BoF) trainer
BOWKMeansTrainer bowTrainer(dictionarySize,tc,retries,flags);
//cluster the feature vectors
Mat dictionary=bowTrainer.cluster(featuresUnclustered);    
//store the vocabulary
FileStorage fs("dictionary.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "vocabulary" << dictionary;
fs.release();
```

Comment: I think you should just compute features on each of the 3 channels separately and cluster them into a BOW. I don't see a point in having 3 BOW.

Comment: @user1965914:actually i came to know that i can use "OpponentColorDescriptorExtractor" but i am unable to use....do you have any idea about it...?

Comment: it converts RGB space to opponent color space and than compute descriptor separately for each space. The final descriptor vector is just a concatenation of each of 3 space.

Comment: depending on your description I would suggest why not use RGB color histogram for color descriptors. Perhaps u can cluster local feature and color into BOW. Just normalise the color vector before doing the clustering